# Next.JS React MongoDB + what service to use for the best Image Upload User App

Tags: mongodb, image, amazon-s3, next.js, file-upload

I'm trying to build an **enterprise**-**level**(almost) app that has one single main functionality: **users can upload & download images**.

Main stack will be:
**Next.JS 13
React
MongoDB** for my database (it's the only one I know how to work with)

The main features the website should have are:
-Image uploading made easy
-users can download photos based on certain permissions
-increased security

I was thinking probably the best approach would be to use an **s3 bucket** (AWS). Basically somehow manage the upload, so when the user presses the upload button, the image is stored in an S3 bucket. Inside MongoDB (the database), only the path to the image will be stored. This way I keep the database as lightweight as possible.

Whenever I need to fetch the user's images, I simply get all image paths associated with the user.

However, I have recently came across **Cloudinary**, which seems to have a dedicated CDN, a better free tier plan (however I'm building the app to possibly go-live perhaps?).

My main concern is:

**For a small test project, that COULD potentially turn into something, would Cloudinary provide me with the necessary resources, or should I go the more traditional and (probably) safer way**?

Huge thanks in advance! I'm new to the whole architecture thing, as I'm trying to evolve from Junior Frontend Developer to Mid. I'm also not very familiar with the Backend, which is why I wanted to do this project in the first place.

Any kind of tips would be HUGELY appreciated. Hope you have a wonderful day!